# Minutes of video shot on Canon dslr

Tags: canon, video

I was wondering if there was a way of identifying how many hours of video has been shot with my canon 70d? Maybe a 3rd party software someone can recommend. It would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no way to determine how much time a Canon EOS camera has been used recording video because Canon cameras keep no record of total time recording video. If they do it is a very closely guarded secret.

Most Canon cameras *do* internally record each time the shutter is activated. It keeps a separate count for activations used to make still images using the viewfinder and for activations used to put the camera into Live View mode, whether for recording still images or video using Live View.

For many Canon EOS cameras the shutter count for still images using the viewfinder can be retrieved using tools based on the Canon *Software Developer's Kit* for specific models. For other models it is more difficult. In either case, the total number of activations reported does *not* include Live View shutter movements.

The internal count for shutter activations used to access Live View can only be retrieved by proprietary hardware/software available to Canon Service Centers and other Canon authorized service providers. When sending a camera to a Canon Service Center for cleaning or repair one can request a shutter count report that will include all shutter actuations in the camera's history (or, if the shutter has been replaced in the past, all actuations since the counter was reset to "zero" following the shutter replacement).

Since I can find no reference to - and have never heard of  - the option to have a report generated revealing the total video recording time for a Canon EOS camera one can probably conclude that such a capability is not built in to Canon EOS cameras.